# Mapping between 3 sheets, write to final sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code that causes my excel to 'not respond' however if I step through put a breakpoint at the loop `For thisScen = 1 To UBound(stressScenMapping, 1)` to `Next thisScen` and run it next by next it works but takes long. When running at once it takes so long. It slows down at this For triple loop.

It does run fast in excel 2010 (3 seconds).
I currently run excel 2013.

Why does it run fast in excel 2010, but 2013 is giving me big issues?

The code does some mapping between sheets and writes to database.

```
Public Sub calc()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim i As Long, thisScen As Long, nRows As Long, nCols As Long


    Dim stressWS As Worksheet
    Set stressWS = Worksheets("EQ_Shocks")
    Unprotect_Tab ("EQ_Shocks")
    nRows = lastWSrow(stressWS)
    nCols = lastWScol(stressWS)

    Dim readcols() As Long
    ReDim readcols(1 To nCols)
    For i = 1 To nCols
        readcols(i) = i
    Next i

    Dim eqShocks() As Variant
    eqShocks = colsFromWStoArr(stressWS, readcols, False)


    'read in database columns
    Dim dataWs As Worksheet
    Set dataWs = Worksheets("database")




    nRows = lastrow(dataWs)
    nCols = lastCol(dataWs)

    Dim dataCols() As Variant
    Dim riskSourceCol As Long
    riskSourceCol = getWScolNum("header1", dataWs)

    ReDim readcols(1 To 4)
    readcols(1) = getWScolNum("header2", dataWs)
    readcols(2) = getWScolNum("header3", dataWs)
    readcols(3) = getWScolNum("header4", dataWs)
    readcols(4) = riskSourceCol

    dataCols = colsFromWStoArr(dataWs, readcols, True)

    'read in scenario mappings
    Dim mappingWS As Worksheet
    Set mappingWS = Worksheets("mapping_ScenNames")

    Dim stressScenMapping() As Variant
    ReDim readcols(1 To 2): readcols(1) = 1: readcols(2) = 2
    stressScenMapping = colsFromWStoArr(mappingWS, readcols, False, 2) 'include two extra columns to hold column number for IR and CR shocks

    For i = 1 To UBound(stressScenMapping, 1)
        stressScenMapping(i, 3) = getWScolNum(stressScenMapping(i, 2), dataWs)
        If stressScenMapping(i, 2) <> "NA" And stressScenMapping(i, 3) = 0 Then
            MsgBox ("Could not find " & stressScenMapping(i, 2) & " column in database")
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next i

    ReDim readcols(1 To 4): readcols(1) = 1: readcols(2) = 2: readcols(3) = 3: readcols(4) = 4
    stressScenMapping = filterOut(stressScenMapping, 2, "NA", readcols)

    'calculate stress and write to database
    Dim thisEqShocks() As Variant

    Dim keepcols() As Long
    ReDim keepcols(1 To UBound(eqShocks, 2))
    For i = 1 To UBound(keepcols)
        keepcols(i) = i
    Next i

    Dim thisCurrRow As Long

    For thisScen = 1 To UBound(stressScenMapping, 1)

        thisEqShocks = filterIn(eqShocks, 2, stressScenMapping(thisScen, 1), keepcols)

        If thisEqShocks(1, 1) = "#EMPTY" Then
            For i = 2 To nRows
                If dataCols(i, 4) <> "stack" And dataCols(i, 4) <> "overflow" And (dataCols(i, 1) = "Equity|Public" Or dataCols(i, 1) = "Equity|Private") Then
                    dataWs.Cells(i, stressScenMapping(thisScen, 3)).value = "No shock found"
                End If
            Next i
        Else 'calculate shocks
            Call quicksort(thisEqShocks, 3, 1, UBound(thisEqShocks, 1))
            For i = 2 To nRows
                If dataCols(i, 4) <> "stack" And dataCols(i, 4) <> "ITS" And (dataCols(i, 1) = "Equity|Public" Or dataCols(i, 1) = "Equity|Private" Or dataCols(i, 1) = "Pref Shares") Then
                    thisCurrRow = findInArrCol(dataCols(i, 3), 3, thisEqShocks)
                    If thisCurrRow = 0 Then 'could not find currency so use generic shock
                        thisCurrRow = findInArrCol("OTHERS", 3, thisEqShocks)
                    End If
                    If thisCurrRow = 0 Then
                        dataWs.Cells(i, stressScenMapping(thisScen, 3)).value = "No shock found"
                    Else
                        dataWs.Cells(i, stressScenMapping(thisScen, 3)).value = Replace(dataCols(i, 2), "-", 0) * (thisEqShocks(thisCurrRow, 4) - 1)
                    End If
                End If
            Next i
        End If

    Next thisScen

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: @Close-Voter(s): the code *does* work as intended, just too slow. Nothing in the OP suggests anything is broken.

Comment: Please [edit] your title to describe the ***purpose* of the code**, not what happens when you run it. Also adding some information about what your code is doing and why it needs to do that would help put everything into context. Right now all we know is that the code is slow. *but what does it do?*

Comment: FWIW Excel going "not responding" only means Excel is busy running your code.

Comment: Missing some key information to help us - you have a number of functions in the code, but have not included these in your question. For example (not an exhaustive list): `Unprotect_Tab` , `lastWSrow`, `lastrow`, `getWScolNum`, `colsFromWStoArr`, `filterOut`. Any of these could contribute to your performance anxiety.

Comment: Are you running versions on the same PC?  Are both the 2010 and 2013 64 bit versions?

Comment: @TinMan, no, different pcs. But PC with 2010 is significantly less powerful as the one running 2013. But both 32 bit , changing to 64 bit isnt really an option.

Comment: I still think that this much difference probably has to do with the computer and not the different version of office,  Possibly an addin or anti-virus program.  This articel has some suggestions: [Excel VBA Macros written for Excel 2007 running very slow on Excel 2016](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_win10-mso_2016/excel-vba-macros-written-for-excel-2007-running/b11c9061-3670-4f5b-bb1b-b7e0feeb2682)

Answer (score 1):

This is essentially what you're doing *on a sheet*

```
FOR every item in stressScenMapping
    Make thisEqShocks
    IF thisEqShocks(1,1) = empty then
        FOR  EVERY ROW
            if EACH ROW IS THESE THEN
                WRITE ON THAT ROW
            END IF
        NEXT
    ELSE sort thisEqShocks
        FOR EVERY ROW
            IF EACH ROW IS THESE THEN
                RETRIEVE VALUE
                IF VALUE = 0 THEN
                    RETRIEVE VALUE AGAIN
                END IF
                IF VALUE = 0 (again) THEN
                    WRITE TO SHEET
                ELSE
                    WRITE TO SHEET
                END IF
            END IF
        NEXT
    END IF      
NEXT
```

Let's put that into words -

```
For every item in this array, create a NEW array
If new array = empty then
For every row on sheet, if that row meets conditions then write on the row
if new array <> empty then
For every row on sheet, if that row meets conditions then get value1
If value1 = 0 then get a new value1
If value1 = 0 then write on the sheet
else write on the sheet
```

So for *every row on the sheet*, you are **checking every row on the sheet** (line 2, 4).

You are writing to sheet on lines 2, 6 and 7. That's three exit points for every row, for every row. If you have 10 rows, it's going to loop 100 times through everything. Seems to me like you would be better off pulling all the rows into an array, do your testing on the array and store what needs to be written on the sheet in an array.

Not to mention all of this is happening **for every item in stressScenMapping**. If you have only 2 items, your 10 rows are going to loop 200 times. See what I mean? It's the same data over and over, just bring it in and test it all at once.

Wouldn't doing something like this allow you to avoid one entire cycle of loops and the need to populate a new array?

```
dim myarr2 as variant
dim myarr3 as variant
redim myarr3(1 to lastrow, 1 to 2)
myarr2 = thissheet.hugerange
for lbound(myarr) to ubound(myarr)
    if myarr2 has stuff then myarr3 = values
    elseif myarr2 has different stuff then myarr3 = things
    else myarr3 = things
    end if
next
```

---

> ```
> Call quicksort(thisEqShocks, 3, 1, UBound(thisEqShocks, 1))
> ```

Call is deprecated. You don't need to `Call` subs, it's obsolete. Instead just use `Sub argument, argument`

---

> ```
> 'calculate stress and write to database
>     Dim thisEqShocks() As Variant
>  Else 'calculate shocks
> If thisCurrRow = 0 Then 'could not find currency so use generic shock
> ```

Comments - ["code tell you how, comments tell you why"](http://blog.codinghorror.com/code-tells-you-how-comments-tell-you-why/). The code should speak for itself, if it needs a comment, it might need to be made more clear. If not, the comment should describe *why* you're doing something rather than *how* you're doing it. Here are a [few reasons](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/254979/125931) to avoid comments all together.

---

> ```
> Dim mappingWS As Worksheet
> Set mappingWS = Worksheets("mapping_ScenNames")
> ```

Worksheets have a `CodeName` property - View Properties window (<kbd>F4</kbd>) and the `(Name)` field (the one at the top) can be used as the worksheet name. This way you can avoid `Sheets("mapping_ScenNames")` and instead just use `nameMap`.

Comment: Thanks Ray. I agree with you. For your suggestion I am having trouble implementing that with my own code, are you available via chat?

Comment: Sorry, been out of country. https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80014/excelguy-raystafarian